# How to send generated barcode to email in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, barcode

I am using **milon/barcode** and it works fine in Laravel views, but the problems is while I send this view to email using Laravel Mail, it display the black div in my email. please help me how to resolve the issue.  thanks

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo DNS2D::getBarcodeHTML("4445645656", "QRCODE"); ?>
</div>
```

Result

[image: the view send to email]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DNS2D::getBarcodeHTML` is class function which will works inside your Laravel application but when you send this to an email address, this class function is not recognizable outside of your application.

**Solution:**
Generate your barcode as image inside your application and then attach it to your email content.

Comment: Thanks, this way worked form me and I solved the problem  by storing the barcode as image first and then send it to email `\Storage::disk('public')->put('test.png',DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath("$applicant_id", "QRCODE"))`

Comment: Welcome and you can use JsBarcode generator as well for that purpose.